# The polynomial $A(x)=x^4+2x^3-5x^2-22x-24$ is divisible by $B(x)=x^2+ax+b$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find for which values of $a$ and $b$ the polynomial $A(x)=x^4+2x^3-5x^2-22x-24$ is divisible by $B(x)=x^2+ax+b$.

We can write $$A(x)=B(x)Q(x)+R(x)$$ where $Q(x)$ is the quotient and $R(x)$ is the remainder. We want to show that $R(x)=0$. The degree of $Q(x)$ is equal to $4-2=2$, so $Q(x)=mx^2+nx+p$.
The degree of $R(x)$ is at most $1$, so we can consider that $R(x)=qx+r$. What to do next?

Comment: Over which field are you working?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I don't understand your question. I am not familiar with the concept of fields in mathematics. Maybe if you ask your question with difference words I can come up with an answer...

Comment: Forget fields. Don't you know that $R(x) = 0$, which makes the $R(x)=qx+r$ part redundant?

Comment: If you are working only with rational numbers or with real numbers, you get a certain answer.  If you are working with complex numbers, you get a different answer. So, the answer to your problem depends upon the numbers that you are working with.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I am working with real numbers only.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, I have just realised that. Now we have $$x^4+2x^3-5x^2-22x-24=mx^4+(n+am)x^3+(p+an+bm)x^2+(ap+bn)x+bp$$ $$\begin{cases}m=1\\n+am=2\\p+an+b=-5\\ap+bn=-22\\bp=-24\end{cases}$$ I am stuck here.

Answer (score 3):

By plugging in small values of $x$ (for example $x=-2,-1,0,1,2,\ldots$), we can note that for $x=3$ and $x=-2\;$, $A(x)=0$. Hence by [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) $(x-3)(x+2)=x^2-x-6$ is a factor of $A(x)$. The other factor can be found by for example long division or other methods. The factorization will be ,
$$x^4+2x^3-5x^2-22x-24=(x^2-x-6)(x^2+3x+4)$$
Hence there are two set of values for $a$ and $b$.